# combinatorics for valid Password with blacklist word

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, combinations, extremal-combinatorics

i have a problem with password combination , let said the min length of pass is 5 and the max is 6

required : min 1 upper, 1 lower and 1 digit

i know to got all the combination of the passoword : 
**(62)^length - (36)^length -(36)^length - (52)^length + (26)^length + (26)^length + (10)^length ..**

The problem is, their have some word are Blacklist :
let say the black list word is rain : so the combination for rain is **(2)^4 "4 is come from length of the string"**

i can get it. but another prblem happend when also have number that can blacklist, lets said, **4 = a/A and i/I = 1. so R41n also black list,**

**i try so hard to find the combination with the ban digit number converting combination,**

maybe someone can help me, for this kind of things..

my point is how to count all valid password with min 1 upper + 1 Low + 1 digit withouth any ban word..

i think i need to specific my case, The rule is : 
// 1 : i/I 
// 3 : e/E 
// 4 : a/A 
// 5 : s/S 
// 7 : t/T 
// 0 : o/O

so, let say the min : 3 and the max : 5 and i have 9 Array 
Black list word : icpc,bio,fbi,cia,yes,no,z,hi,abcdefg

we can try with abcdefg, z, and yes

Thank you..

Comment: Can't you be more explicit about what exactly you'd like to solve? As far as I understand, you need a total number of valid not-banned passwords?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes Sir, you're correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's count the number of 5-character passwords containing "rain" that are valid:

Total 5-character passwords containing rain: $2\cdot 62\cdot 36$.
Total with "rain" or "RAIN" (this cannot be extended to a valid 5-character password as it will be missing one of upper, lower, or digit): $2\cdot 62\cdot 2$
Total with no number (not all caps or all lower, as we counted those already): $2\cdot 52\cdot 14$
Total with either no lower or no upper (there are 3 ways to write "rain" with no lower case letters that are not all uppercase and 3 ways to write it with no uppercase that are not all lower case): $2\cdot 36\cdot 6$

Total 5-character passwords that have at least 1 upper, 1 lower, 1 digit AND "rain": $2(62\cdot 34-52\cdot 14-36\cdot 6)$
Total 5-character passwords that have at least 1 upper, 1 lower,  and 1 digit (may or may not have "rain"): $62^5-52^5-2\cdot 36^5+10^5+2\cdot 26^5$

Total valid 5-character passwords:
$62^5-52^5-2\cdot 36^5+10^5+2\cdot 26^5-2(62\cdot 34-52\cdot 14-36\cdot 6)$

Total 6-character passwords that include "rain": $3\cdot 62^2\cdot 36$
Total 6-character passwords that include "rain", but no digit: $3\cdot 52^2\cdot 16$
Total 6-character passwords that include "rain", but no uppercase or no lowercase letter (but do include a digit): $3\cdot 36^2\cdot 8-3\cdot 26^2\cdot 2$
Total 6-character passwords that include "rain" and at least 1 upper, 1 lower, and 1 digit: $3(62^2\cdot 36-52^2\cdot 16-36^2\cdot 8+26^2\cdot 2)$

Total 6-character valid 6-character passwords:
$$62^6-52^6-2\cdot 36^6+10^6+2\cdot 26^6-3(62^2\cdot 36-52^2\cdot 16-36^2\cdot 8+26^2\cdot 2)$$

Total valid passwords:
$$62^5-52^5-2\cdot 36^5+10^5+2\cdot 26^5-2(62\cdot 34-52\cdot 14-36\cdot 6)+62^6-52^6-2\cdot 36^6+10^6+2\cdot 26^6-3(62^2\cdot 36-52^2\cdot 16-36^2\cdot 8+26^2\cdot 2)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir,

but if rain  : a/A = 4 ; i/I = 1 and r41n / r4in/ra1n also unvalid, how can i count for all the valid password ? as far that i understand from your answer, that rain only letter, how about it can be number ? Thank you Sir.

Comment: That is included. The first character of "rain" is in the set $\{r,R\}$. The second character is in the set $\{a,A,4\}$. The third character is in the set $\{i,I,1\}$. The last character in the set $\{n,N\}$. Total ways to write "rain" is 36. (That's why you see several 36's when I describe total passwords containing "rain").

Comment: i almost get it with your explanation :
But i am a little bit confuse about huge case, i think i need to specific my case,

The rule is :
// 1 : i/I
                // 3 : e/E
                // 4 : a/A
                // 5 : s/S
                
                // 7 : t/T
                // 8 : 
                // 9 : 
                // 0 : o/O

so, let say the min : 3 and the max : 5
and i have 9 Array Black list word : icpc,bio,fbi,cia,yes,no,z,hi,abcdefg

Maybe we can try with abcdefg, z, and yes,

you get 2 for 5 length and 3 for 6 length from (length - 3 ) right ?

Comment: **2(62⋅34−52⋅14−36⋅6)** this is 34 or you just typo from 36 Sir ?

Comment: The 34 is not a typo. It is $62\cdot 36-62\cdot 2 = 62\cdot 34$

Comment: i know to get this **Total N-character passwords that have at least 1 upper, 1 lower, and 1 digit (may or may not have The blacklist word)**, but its difficult to me to get the **Total N-character passwords that have at least 1 upper, 1 lower, 1 digit AND blacklist word** any Hint sir or any method ?

Comment: Basically, I was using the Inclusion/Exclusion principle. Read up on that, and hopefully it will clear things up.

Comment: Thank you Sir, i will read it now, and try to solve my problem ASAP,

Thanks for helping..

Comment: if start with 3 charater it's means it will break the 1 low 1 up 1 digit rules like sir ? 
the blacklist word is "ata" so how can i do with this sir ?

Comment: The more constraints you add, the more complicated the Inclusion/Exclusion becomes. The process is the same, it just becomes much more complex the more constraints you add.

Comment: Sir, how if the length of text only 4. can you please help me to explain as same as you explain for text length 5 and 6 ? thank you Sir..

Comment: Total # of 4-character passwords with at least 1 digit, one upper- and one lower-case letter: $62^4-52^4-2\cdot 36^4+10^4+2\cdot 26^4-14$

The 14 is because there are 14 ways to create the word "rain" that are otherwise valid passwords.

Comment: may i know why 14 Sir and how 14 come Sir ? 
Why not 36 ? that come From
{r,R} . The second character is in the set {a,A,4}. The third character is in the set {i,I,1}. The last character in the set {n,N}. Total ways to write "rain" is 36.

Comment: Because "rain" is not an otherwise valid password. It does not have any uppercase or digit.
The valid passwords can have 1 digit, 1 uppercase, and two lowercase: 6 ways (r4iN,r4In,R4in,ra1N,rA1n,Ra1n)
1 digit, 2 uppercase, 1 lowercase: 6 ways (R4In,R4iN,r4IN,RA1n,Ra1N,rA1N)
2 digits, 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase: 2 ways (r41N,R41n)

Comment: Ok Sir, Thank you, the Job i should do now, translate into coding..
Thank you sir..